# Could you please help me understand the discrepancy metric?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am trying to understand the discrepancy metric and its properties. It is defined as $$d_D(\mu,\nu):=\sup_{\small \mbox{ all closed balls}\,\, B}|\mu(B)-\nu(B)|$$

for probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $\Omega$. What should I understand from all closed balls $B$? How do I apply a measure to a closed ball? is there a nice example?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Big Disclaimer, I am asking the same question, but I found [another definition](http://books.google.com/books?id=I-PQH8gcOjUC&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=explain%20%22discrepancy%20metric%22&source=bl&ots=5bU1c5yrHK&sig=iqjSqT5peEyJgC1-CLogDPJ8ymU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SudFVMz_EdD2iQKT3IEY&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=explain%20%22discrepancy%20metric%22&f=false):

$dD(μ,ν) :=sup \{|μ(X \in B)−ν(X \in B)|: B $ is any closed ball$\}$

So I'm interpreting it as follows (please correct if wrong):

Apply the measures $\mu$, $\nu$ to all closed balls $B$ in your probability space as follows:

$μ(B) = \mathop{\cup}_{x \in B} \mu(x) = \mathop{\sum}_{x \in B} \mu(x)$.

The discrepancy metric is the least upper bound of the difference between the two metrics applied to all closed balls.

Comment: I think $\mu (\mathop{\cup}_{x \in B}x)$, But simply I have say two mean shifted Gaussian densities. How to calculate it?